# How does system.Threading.Timer works?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

We are trying to implement timer based background calls. I would like to understand  does the following code, blocks any thread?

```
new Timer(0=> functioncall(), null,1440*60000,-1)
```

any insights about timer class would be helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally `System.Timers.Timer` is more commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

It schedules a timer that will invoke your callback on a worker thread when the timer hits. Your callback will obviously tie up that worker for some (hopefully short) amount of time. The thread that schedules the timer isn't actively blocked, although it does need to mutate the timer queue which has some synchronization demands for thread-safety (in case multiple threads are scheduling/cancelling timers at the same time).